# Allowing sessions on multiple sites

Tags: php, api, session

I am working on a site that has a login API. So when people login on my site, they will automatically be logged in to other sites.

Is their way by which a session can be setup so that other websites can use it? If not, is their any other solution?

Comment: Either your multiple sites are on same server and with in same package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way - you can store your session values in database, and can use in other sites. :)

Example:-

let suppose if my site is deployed on multiple servers and end user might be redirected to different servers accordingly to traffic, then it would be good to save the session values in db.

Comment: I can but how will they be able to access info that is stored on my database?

Comment: @user3001689: you can access the information through cURL library - send the request to desired server and when getting the response, can user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible using in example [Redis](http://redis.io/) for the session storage. You should look for configuring php sessions to use custom storage. Here is php man for this http://php.net/session.customhandler

Comment: I think redis is used for caching.

Comment: You can use it both for caching and storing your sessions. Redis is not cahce mechanism it's key->value storage.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably using a cookie that is spread over your whole domain. This cookie can then be linked to a session. I'm currently working on something like this on Symfony2.

As example:
login.mydomain.com
application.mydomain.com
etc.mydomain.com

login.* will obviously contain my login logic + forms etc. This will also contain an API which the other applications can verify the cookie to. My Application will first check if the user is logged in. If not, it will check if it has the required cookie. If it does not, it will redirect to the login.* login page.

If it does have the cookie, it will validate this in my login.* API. Expired > redirect to the login page, if not it will return the required info of that user and "login" to my application.

The only problem I have at the moment is storing the session. I use mcrypt to encrypt the contents and store it in mysql (cookie_id, cookie_contents). I have but 1 problem, it doesn't automatically purge the expired sessions, I still have to find a solution for this.

What you are basically looking for is Single Sign-On (just a guess, but I think accurate).